# PHP - Printing 4 tables per line out of a total of 12, skips table 5 and 10, it isn't supposed to

Tags: php, modulus

```
$rowcount=0;
$prodcount=0;

while (($record = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "|")) !== FALSE) { 

//here, the csv file is opened

$numrecords = count($record);

$produs=$record[1]; //records read
$pret=$record[3];
$imagine=$record[4];

if ($rowcount < $linecount) { 

//linecount is the number of lines in my csv file and i take 1 from it. for some reason it shows one extra entry when i use count()

    if($rowcount > 0) //this line skips the first csv line (table head)
    {
        if ($rowcount %5 != 0) {
//this line is where my problem lies. i think it's because of the modulus operator

            if ($prod_count==5) {$prod_count="1";} 
            if ($prod_count==1) {print ("<tr>");} //these two lines limit the drawn tables to 4 per row

            print "some table";
        }else {

//this line is where I think i can fix it. Just need to decrement $rowcount by one. $rowcount -= 1; thing is: it doesn't work for some reason when i take 1 from $rowcount, the whole script freezes and only displays 4 table out of 12, which is the number of rows minus the first one in my csv file.

            $table_lastrow=0;
            if ($rowcount <= $linecount){
                print ("</tr><tr><td height='30'></td></tr>");

            }

        }
    }}

$rowcount++;
$prod_count++;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand what you want - is a 4x3 table from your 12 records in the CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want right, you have made this a lot more complicated with many extra variables that are not required for this.

See if the following code produces what you are expecting (note that this produces a table with no data in it, which is what your code produces, because you never use `$produs`, `$pret` or `$imagine` anywhere):

```
// Do this here to skip the header row
fgetcsv($handle, 1000);

echo "<table>\n  <tr>\n";

for ($prod_count = 0; ($record = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "|")) !== FALSE; $prod_count++) { 

  $numrecords = count($record);
  $produs = $record[1];
  $pret = $record[3];
  $imagine = $record[4];

  if ($prod_count < $linecount) {
    if ($prod_count && (!$prod_count % 4)) echo "  </tr>\n  <tr>\n";
    echo "    <td height='30'></td>\n";
  }

}

echo "  </tr>\n</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this fits more the thing you want .. read in the lines and put the first line in the first column, second in the second, third in the third and 4. in the 4. - 5. is skipped and 6. again in the first column ....

```
$rowcount=0; 

// skip header row
fgetcsv($handle, 1000);

print "<table>";

while (($record = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "|")) !== FALSE) { 
    if ($rowcount%5 == 0) print '<tr>'; //open row

    if ($rowcount%5 == 4) ;//skip 5. row 
    else print "<td>data</td>";

    if ($rowcount%5 == 3) print '</tr>'; //close row
    $rowcount++;
}
//need to be at the end because the if statement would otherwise never fulfill
//if ($rowcount <= $linecount)
print ("<tr><td height='30'></td></tr></table>");
```